# How to make apt recognize an installed tar package?

Tags: apt, java

I've installed Oracle Java. I want to be able to remove OpenJDK, but when trying to do so `apt` wants to install another version of Java.

How can I configure `apt` so that it knows I already have a third-party Java installed so I can remove these OpenJDK packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Create a dummy package](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html) using [equivs](http://packages.debian.org/equivs). In a nutshell:

1. Create a control file for the dummy package. The program `equiv-controls` creates a template. Give it a file name.

   ```
   equivs-control oracle-jre.control
   ```
2. Edit the control file. At least set the `Package:` line to `sun-java6-jre` (the name of the defunct Sun/Oracle Java package). You should also write a meaningful `Description:`, set the section to `java`. Declare that the package `Provides: java-6-runtime` and other versions (this is the virtual package that other programs depend on, can find this out by checking what `openjdk-6-jre` provides and what various programs require). The file might look like this:

   ```
   Section: java
   Priority: optional
   Standards-version: 3.9.2
   Package: sun-6-jre
   Provides: java6-runtime, java-runtime
   Description: dummy package when Oracle Java is installed
   ```
3. Create a Debian package with the control file you created. This package is only there for the dependencies and installs no file.

   ```
   equivs-build oracle-jre.control
   ```
4. Install the resulting deb package.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i sun-6-jre_1.0_all.deb
   ```

Comment: How are updates of the old package (sun-6-jre) handled when running apt-get upgrade? Ignored? (ps: your first link is broken)

Comment: @assylias Updates are handled normally: apt will install the most recent version of the package by that name, if there is one. You'd normally craft a package manually because it doesn't exist in the distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a method for doing this. In lieu of using a PPA repository that provides you with `.deb` packages of Java, you could give [this script](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6) a try which will roll you're own .deb packages of the Java installation.

This script is called [OAB-Java](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6), specifically `oab-java.sh`.

#### Example

Downloading the script:

```
cd ~/
wget https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/raw/0.2.8/oab-java.sh -O oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh
```

The script takes the following switches:

- `-7` : Build oracle-java7 packages instead of sun-java6
- `-c` : Remove pre-existing packages from `/var/local/oab/deb` and sources from `/var/local/oab/src`.
- `-k` : Use the specified existing key instead of generating one
- `-s` : Skip building if the packages already exist
- `-t` : Specify the Java version tag to use from the upstream Debian packaging script.
- `-h` : This help

To prepare & install the Oracle 6 `.deb` files:

```
$ sudo ./oab-java.sh
$ sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

To prepare & install the Oracle 7 `.deb` files:

```
$ sudo ./oab-java.sh -7
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jre
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above given by @Gilles worked perfectly for me for a while. With Java 8 and newer versions of Ubuntu, though, it doesn't work. Following is the `oracle-jre.control` file I now use.

```
Section: java
Priority: optional
Standards-version: 3.9.2
Package: sun-8-jre
Provides: default-jre, openjdk-8-jre, openjfx
Description: Dummy package when Oracle Java is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a hold on a package with apt-mark.

Hold:

```
sudo apt-mark hold package_name
```

Unhold:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold package_name
```

That will prevent apt from touching it.