# How will apt-get handle my manual installed software?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, emacs, deb

Suppose the Emacs version in the APT repository is 24.3, I `configure && make install` my own emacs 24.4. After a long time, the software in the APT repository was updated to 24.5. What would APT do when I run `apt-get update && atp-get safeupgrade`?

What's the general way to let APT handle my manual installed software?

Comment: I believe you use `auto-apt`.  See the [AptGet Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

Comment: Did you manually install Emacs in `/usr/local/bin` or into `usr/bin`?

Comment: When you did the manual installation of emacs, was there an existing installation of emacs on your system that had been installed using apt-get or dpkg which was partially or totally overwritten by your manual installation?

Comment: @slm @Mark Plotnick Thank you. I installed into /usr/bin. After reading @Bytor 's answer, I think I'd better clean up and manually install Emacs to `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apt-get does not have a "safeupgrade" command. Are you thinking of "aptitude safe-upgrade"?

That aside, apt-get only "knows" things because the package system maintains a database of all the changes the package subsystem programs makes. When you download source and build it yourself and then install it, that is not done using the package subsystem so none of the those changes are recorded anywhere so apt-get simply cannot know about them.

If you never did "apt-get install emacs" on your computer, the package subsystem will never know that emacs is installed so "apt-get upgrade" will never touch it and you are safe. Only programmes listed in "dpkg --list" will be processed by "apt-get upgrade".

If you did do "apt-get install emacs", that's a different story.

If you were smart enough to use "./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin" (and possibly a few other parameters specifying locations), then your custom emacs' files will be in different locations than what "apt-get install emacs" loaded on your system, and you'll have two working installations of emacs. So when you do "apt-get upgrade" and there is a newer package of emacs in the repository than what apt-get put there before, it will replace that and your custom version will not be touched.

If you didn't use the configure options when building the custom emacs, it probably wrote them over top if the files of the packaged emacs. But that really depends upon what options the package maintainer used when they built the .deb to place in the repository, so it is slightly unpredictable. In any case, Anything that was over-written by your custom install will get get over-written again when you do apt-get upgrade. After each install you will only have one working version of emacs with a few extraneous odds and ends.

Answer (score 1):

APT doesn't know anything about your manually-installed software.

If you installed Emacs under `/usr/local` (the default location), that installation is completely independent from the Emacs installation under `/usr` managed by APT. Running `emacs` will run `/usr/local/bin/emacs` (your manual installation); running `/usr/bin/emacs` will run the Emacs installed by APT (more specifically, the most recent version — Debian's¹ Emacs packaging supports installing multiple versions).

If you installed Emacs in `/usr` — well, you've created a mess, but hopefully not a big one. `/usr` is reserved for the package manager, except `/usr/local` which is for the system administrator (the package manager only creates a few directories there). Run `make uninstall` from the Emacs source directory to remove these files. Do this before reinstalling the Debian packages.

If you want to install software manually (under `/usr/local`) but declare it to the package manager to fulfill dependencies, you can make a fake package with `equivs`. See [How to make apt recognize an installed tar package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85928/how-to-make-apt-recognize-an-installed-tar-package/86052#86052)

Debian automatically byte-compiles Elisp packages for the installed versions of Emacs. To benefit from this, install a version of Emacs through the package manager in addition to the manually installed one. Make sure to pick one with compatible bytecode ([an older minor version with the same major version should be ok](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/portability-of-bytecode-between-emacs-versions/3438#3438), e.g. a 24.3 deb and a 24.4 manual installation). Make the manually installed version read the same bytecode directories: load `/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/startup.elc` from your local installation's `startup.el`.

¹  <sub>In this post, “Debian” includes derivatives that use the same Emacs packaging, including Ubuntu, Mint, etc.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Before I get familiar with `equivs`, I'd stick clean with the apt repository.