# apt-get install - when running installed program: no such file or directory

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, ghostscript

I have installed and build `ghostscript` and `graphicsmagick` from source

Have deleted both directories because I want to install them via apt-get

```
apt-get install --reinstall graphicsmagick ghostscript
```

When running `gs` or `gm` I either get the old version or no such file/directory

What is wrong?

Comment: `apt purge` and `install` again

Comment: What directories did you delete? Where did you install them to from source? If you ran `make install` (or equivalent), then the programs would be installed under `/usr/local`. It would then depend on your `$PATH` if you get these executables or the ones installed using `apt`.

Comment: I used via `make install` and I deleted the source/build dirs.. Seems to work after I deleted `/usr/bin/gs` and `/usr/bin/gm` and made a reinstall

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/533115/edit) to contain the complete "no such file/directory" error, including the filename that can't be found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How will apt-get handle my manual installed software?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169792/how-will-apt-get-handle-my-manual-installed-software)