# apt-get install imagemagick - doesn't work with previous make install

Tags: apt, make

I have previous installed `imagemagick` from source via `make install` on my Debian.

Now I want to install via `apt-get install imagemagick` but it doesn't work

Have tried to delete all binary files

```
rm \
/usr/bin/animate \
/usr/bin/compare \
/usr/bin/composite \
/usr/bin/conjure \
/usr/bin/convert \
/usr/bin/display \
/usr/bin/identify \
/usr/bin/import \
/usr/bin/mogrify \
/usr/bin/montage \
/usr/bin/stream
```

Then I reinstalled it via `apt-get install --reinstall imagemagick`

Imagemagick is installing, but can not run `convert` afterwards

`which convert` does not output any path and `/usr/bin/convert` is not present

## update

I have now tried to install it via a deb file, but it still doesn't work

```
cd /var/bin && wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i imagemagick_6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1_amd64.deb
```

`which convert` does not output any path and `/usr/bin/convert` is not present

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533115/apt-get-install-when-running-installed-program-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I created that question.. but the solution does not work with this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How will apt-get handle my manual installed software?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169792/how-will-apt-get-handle-my-manual-installed-software)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us any errors you get, "it doesn't work" doesn't help us help you.

Comment: @JigglyNaga why is that a duplicate? That's about how apt will work with existing packages, it doesn't answer this question (how can I install something I previously installed from source).

Comment: @terdon It's the same underlying problem.  The answers explain why you'll have difficulty if you install from source then try to use apt-get, and how you might recover from it.

Comment: @JigglyNaga none of the answers seems relevant. Normally, `apt install foo` will just overwrite any existing `foo` files, so the OP is experiencing something odd. Clarkk, did you also try simply `apt install imagemagick`? Since you didn't install with `apt` originally, the `--reinstall` isn't relevant.

Comment: The possible duplicate is not relevant to my question.. I did install it before I used `--reinstall`

Comment: @JigglyNaga the possible duplicate does only explain how apt works.. It is not relevant to this question

Comment: @JigglyNaga please remvoe the possible duplicate

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, but I think those answers are still relevant reading for your situation.

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -V imagemagick`?

Comment: `dpkg -V imagemagick` does not output anything.. even though I have just installed imagemagick via a DEB file.. see the question update

Comment: `dpkg -V` outputs nothing if it didn't find a problem, so that suggests the package is intact.  `convert` is managed by the ["alternatives" system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives); what output do you get from `update-alternatives --display convert`?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I desided to format the server and install everything from the `apt`. Now it works

Answer (score -1):

The file should be part of package *graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat* on Debian.