# Make sure package can not be deleted

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

I have some PCs running various types of debian testing to have the latest version of a number of packages. Usually this works great for my usage, but occasionally, an apt-get dist-upgrade wants to remove packages I will keep on my PC due to some incompabilities with some upgraded packages. Can I somehow in apt.conf tell apt that a certain package should not be removed. I know about the version pinning, but I do want the package to be upgraded, if appliciable, I just do not want the package to be removed to have another package upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to [create a dummy package](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html) using [equivs](http://packages.debian.org/equivs). See [How to make apt recognize an installed tar package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85928/how-to-make-apt-recognize-an-installed-tar-package/86052#86052) for a quick how-to. Give your package the `required` priority and the `Essential` status so that apt will never ever think of uninstalling it, and declare the packages you never ever want to uninstall as dependencies of it.

```
Section: local
Priority: required
Essential: yes
Package: mortensickel-dependencies
Depends: package1, package2, package3-1 | package3-2
Description: Depend on my absolutely required packages
```

Comment: A bit more difficult that I thought - I hoped I had overlooked some settings in apt.conf - but it works, thanks.